# Mod Rewrite: apply to all js and css files except 

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to apply a minify actions to all the javascript and CSS files, except the ones I indicate.

I have this condition and rule that applies to all the files (css and js):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)(js|css)$ minify.php?q=$1$2 [L,NC]
```

I need to add the conditions to say:

Apply to all except: jquery.js, prototype.js, etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*jquery.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*prototype.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)(js|css)$ minify.php?q=$1$2 [L,NC]
```

The key to this is the inversion of the regex using the "!" (exclamation point) to say the file name is not jquery.js and not prototype.js and it can be found on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RewriteCond` to specify on which conditions the `RewriteRule` should be applied. So prepend these lines to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !jquery.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !prototype.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this! I've been searching for this answer to my problem for almost a month. My problem was how to rewrite some files to https and the rest to http, but I was able to modify above to make it work. Here's a chunk of my code. (I have a lot more files in the real .htaccess on the site.)

```
#################################################################
# To only change certain files from http to https, the rest from 
# https to http. Absolute links are set up throughout the site, 
# but if a visitor for some reason edits the URL in the address
# bar, the URL will change back to the proper format.

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alvingolf\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*contact-us.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*register-for-tournaments.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*form.htm$
```